# Set the color of selected text

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm setting up the theme for my app and I want to go with a minimalistic black & white color palette. For that I want the text to look black in a normal state and white when it's selected with the selection color being black.

So far I have found a way to set the selection color to black but now it just blends with the text because the color of the selected text stays black too. Is there a way to set the color of selected text?

```
TemeData(
  textSelectionTheme: TextSelectionThemeData(
    cursorColor: Colors.black,
    selectionColor: Colors.black,
  ),
);
```

What I want:

[image: what I want]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found anything in the Flutter library, but you can try to use this Widget:

```
class SelectableColoredText extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;
  final TextStyle? style;
  final Color selectedColor;
  final Color selectedBackgroundColor;

  const SelectableColoredText(this.text, {
    Key? key,
    this.style,
    required this.selectedColor,
    required this.selectedBackgroundColor,
  }) : super(key: key);
  
  @override
  _SelectableColoredTextState createState() => _SelectableColoredTextState();
}

class _SelectableColoredTextState extends State<SelectableColoredText> {
  int? _start;
  int? _end;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final int start = _start ?? widget.text.length;
    final int end = _end ?? widget.text.length;
    return SelectableText.rich(
      TextSpan(
        style: widget.style ?? Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,
        children: [
          // Text before the selection
          TextSpan(text: widget.text.substring(0, start)),
          // Selected text
          TextSpan(
            text: widget.text.substring(start, end),
            style: TextStyle(
              color: widget.selectedColor, 
              backgroundColor: widget.selectedBackgroundColor,
            ),
          ),
          // Text after the selection
          TextSpan(text: widget.text.substring(end, widget.text.length)),
        ],
      ),
      // Update the start and end positions of the selection
      onSelectionChanged: (selection, _) {
        final int newStart = min(selection.baseOffset, selection.extentOffset);
        final int newEnd = max(selection.baseOffset, selection.extentOffset);
        if (_start == newStart && _end == newEnd) return;
        setState(() {
          _start = newStart;
          _end = newEnd;
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

You can use it like that:

```
SelectableColoredText(
  'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog',
  // The default text style
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40, color: Colors.black),
  // The color of the selected text
  selectedColor: Colors.white,
  // The background color of the selected text
  selectedBackgroundColor: Colors.black,
)
```

Comment: Thanks! It's weird that flutter doesn't have this feature. You would think it's pretty common...

Answer (score 0):

Sett the textSelectionColor for its ThemeData.

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't work. It says it's deprecated and redirects me to use `TextSelectionThemeData.selectionColor` which is what I'm already using and it sets the color of the selection itself, not the text's